# Bar top with live edge slabs and 90 degree turn with live edge "round" at the corner

Tags: wood, design, live-edge

I am working with Eastern White Pine. I have 12' slabs, approximately 2.5" thick, with live edge and I am making a bar top. The final finish is planned to be clear epoxy. This is for a bar in an interior, above-grade, conditioned space.

The bar is "L"-shaped, approximately 11' long turning 90 degrees to a section approximately 3' long. This 3' return projects toward the barkeep - the patrons are on the long side. The bar top projects toward the patrons approximately 12" from the front of the wall that supports the bar.

Regarding the design, the first thought for the turn was to do a mitered joint. A second thought was to perhaps do the turn with two mitered joints (with a section of live edge between the joints) to make the corner more "curved."

This eventually led to a third thought: What if we put a cross-cut section of log/stump in the corner, with the adjoining slabs shaped around it. The idea is to have a large enough "round" piece that the "point" of the corner is the exposed live edge of the "round" piece. This would also provide visual interest as the end-grain of the round would show the rings of the tree, while the slabs would show grain (generally) running the length of the bar.

I have been unable to find any examples of this kind of design in my google searches. It might simply be that I am unaware of the proper terms to search. Or it could be that such a design looks stupid in practice, or is not practical to create. I see lots of tables that are cross sections of interesting trees. I see lots of tables and bars that are made from slabs. I cannot find examples the combine the two.

Is this option a viable design?

Comment: Too many questions, sorry. SE sites work best with a single question that attracts good answers that will satisfy the question. Your questions goes from design to construction details to installation, and no one is going to write an answer that addresses all that. Recommend you break this up into multiple questions, each focused on single aspect of your project. Make sure take the [tour], if you have not already, to get an idea of what I mean.

Comment: One major query per Q Rob! Secondary related queries to the main thing being asked are fine, but only if there are one or two and they don't require much in the way of typing. As it covers in the Help, *Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.* I like to expand on this a bit and say if you can imagine a magazine article would be needing it's asking too much. But, there's no limit to the number of questions you can ask here so it's perfectly fine to break this down into individual Q&As. [contd]

Comment: Re. the first 2 ways you outline to turn the corner, I've seen both done and it's really a matter of personal preference. I don't really like the 45 piece in the corner of the two-mitre version visually, but practically I guess it works well. And a single mitre means only two joint surfaces to cut perfectly. Just to tack it on, epoxy is going to fail eventually and it's impossible to repair — unlike varnish, truly impossible; with varnish 'impossible' means difficult/v. difficult (or not viable time-wise). So in due course the owner is looking at a hellish refinishing job, or replacement.

Comment: Edited to ask one question.

Comment: Much better, Rob! I agree that the round for the corner would look really cool. My main concern would be wood expansion. You mention length and thickness, but don't indicate the width of the pieces. They will expand in width, and the round will want to get larger in diameter. You could run into issues with checks and splits if your attachment doesn't allow for some wood movement. In theory, a single attachment in the center of the width to the appropriate location on the round would be the way to allow that, but may not be a strong enough joint.

Comment: I think it will be hard to find a  crosscut piece that is large enough to visually meet your two main pieces.  One alternative might be to place a wide (6-8"?) board to accept both intersecting miter ends of the two counters( at 45 degrees to both slabs). Its outside edge could round or miter the corner profile. Inserting this piece will help resolve the different profiles of each live edge slab. You could use a slotted connection between the two tops and this miter board to address differential expansion rates (check out how 'bread board' ends work.